# Set ylim on subplot secondary y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yaxis

I want to plot the data in subplots using secondary axes. I can set the ylim but it affects only the secondary y-axis (on the right side). I can't find a way to control the ylim on the primary y-axis (on the left side). I'd like the primary y-axis to have a limit of [0,40], and the secondary y-axis to have a limit of [0,100].

---

```
#import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import string
%pylab inline
%matplotlib inline

# READ IN FIRST CSV
espr = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
df_e = pd.DataFrame(espr)

#READ IN SECOND CSV
heat = pd.read_csv('heat.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1',low_memory=False)
heat = heat[2:]
df_h = pd.DataFrame(heat,dtype='float64')
df_h = df_h.reset_index(drop=True)

#READ IN THIRD CSV
temp = pd.read_csv('temp.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1',low_memory=False)
temp = temp[2:]
df_t = pd.DataFrame(temp,dtype='float64')
df_t = df_t.reset_index(drop=True)

# CONCATENATE DATAFRAMES
df_e = df_e[[' building:time step (-)', ' building:zone 01:air point:temperature (oC)', ' building:zone 05:air point:temperature (oC)']]
df_h = df_h[['TIME', 'Tdb_amb']]
df_t = df_t[['Tavg_diurn', 'Tavg_seas']]
sim = pd.concat([df_h, df_t, df_e],axis=1)

# SEPARATE DATA FOR PLOTTING
mar = sim[14160:21600]
```

This is where I'm running into a wall, I've read about setting twinx() to set properties for different axes but whenever I try to implement it, it tells me it doesn't know what twinx is.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
fig.set_figheight(25)
fig.set_figwidth(20)

mar[' building:zone 01:air point:temperature (oC)'].plot(ax=axes[0])
mar[' building:zone 05:air point:temperature (oC)'].plot(ax=axes[0])
mar['Tavg_diurn'].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=axes[0])
mar['Tavg_seas'].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=axes[0])
ylim([0,100])

fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it tells me it doesn't know what twinx is"?  Can you update your question with the exact (and full) stack trace message that shows up?

Answer (score 10):

Well if `axes` is an array of the two axes then you could do:

```
axes[0].set_ylim(0, 40)
axes[1].set_ylim(0, 100)
```

or using `pyplot's twinx()` you could try:

```
axes[0] = ax2.twinx()
axes[0].set_ylim(0, 40)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

Answer (score 9):

The key is this: `axes[0].right_ax.set_ylim(0,100)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=True)

columns = [' building:zone 01:air point:temperature (oC)', ' building:zone 05:air point:temperature (oC)',
           'Tavg_diurn', 'Tavg_seas']
mar = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=1000), columns=columns)
mar = mar.cumsum()
mar.plot(ax=axes[0], secondary_y=['Tavg_diurn', 'Tavg_seas'])
axes[0].set_ylim(0,40)
axes[0].right_ax.set_ylim(0,100)
```

[image: A matplotlib figure resulting form the above code]

Comment: Please add an explanation what you've changed and why it should fix OP's problem

Comment: Whoops, thanks @jmattheis, I realized my two explanations were the same. I shortened and simplified to be more clear.